# Excel conditional formating: query cell color

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I know how to use the conditional formatting.

I apply a color to some cell based on values.

I have a lot of lines, each for a different product and for each product a list of values in rows.

With the conditional formatting I can set a color depending the values.

Now the question : For each product name, I set manually a cell color and I want to use THIS product color to be used by the conditional formatting to be applied on the values (not a color fixed in the dialog box).

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always surprised by the nooks and crannies of Excel, but it looks like the answer is "no". The function that should have this feature would be the `CELL` function, in which you can query for metadata about cells, but the `"color"` attribute of this function does not return the actual color of a cell, but rather is a binary attribute. [More info here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF)